# How to bring up text on image in uipickerview

Tags: ios4, uipickerview, xcode4.6, ios6.1

Before insert image in uipickerview 
[image]

After insert image in uipickerview

[image]

```
- (UIView *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
  CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.5, 255, 250);
   UIImageView *label = [[UIImageView alloc]
                           initWithFrame:imageFrame];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
  [label sendSubviewToBack:pview];

 [pview sendSubviewToBack: label];
  [pview addSubview:label];


 return label;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have written this:-

```
[label sendSubviewToBack:pview];

 [pview sendSubviewToBack: label];
```

I think you are doing mistake here..

you just use this:-

```
[label sendSubviewToBack:pview];
[label addSubview:pview];
```

remove this

```
 [pview sendSubviewToBack: label];
```

it will work fine..if not feel free to ask..enjoy..

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=A0B31648B2E37C13&id=A0B31648B2E37C13!106

@json  its my file

Comment: @Harshad  its working nice whats the problem in your project??please comment fast..have hurry to go...

Comment: i made comment on method just remove them then run app @json